# Remooving reccurent entries in a table Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, bids

I have created a table in Visual Studio. That table has two columns. First is the name of a parent and second is the child name. In case one parent has several children I would like his name to appear only once (Not sure if it matters, but the data is being generated from SSMS and the environment I am using in Visual Studio is called bids).

For example:

```
Name      Child_Name
Gil       Mike
          Eduardo
Victoria  Tanya
          Pamela
```

And not:

```
Name      Child_Name
Gil       Mike
Gil       Eduardo
Victoria  Tanya
Victoria  Pamela
```

How can I do that in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to find a solution for this problem after all.
1) In visual studio go to Layout tab.
2) Right click on the column.
3) Choose expressions.
4) Go to common functions.
5) Go to Miscellaneous.
6) Use the function Previous to compare the current field value to the previous field value. For example:

```
iif(Fields!name.Value = Previous(Fields!name.Value), "", Fields!name.Value)
```